# Is it a good design to use class style in material-ui react component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react website and trying to use `material-ui` component. I found that `material-ui` suggests put `styles` in components' `classes` property. Each component can use `className={...}` to take the styles.

```
...
return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
 ...
```

Do I have to follow this design if I choose to use `material-ui`? Or can I create `sass` file separately and import them in each component? If I do that, is it against `material-ui` design? Or will I miss any `material-ui` features?

Comment: Answer to your all questions is **NO**. You can use `sass` file to separate out your `css` and hence your code will become ease to maintain. None of the `material-ui` feature will get missed.

Answer (score 0):

If the styles are specific to the component, it is fine to keep the styles with that component and use classes as you have done.

If the styles or functionality are shared across components it may be best to import them.

Due to the rise in popularity of css-in-js Material UI has moved towards the [material ui css in js](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/) approach.

The [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/) library was one of the first to adopt this approach and has become popular since developers liked the approach of leveraging tagged template literals. It ties in nicely with React.

There are 3 different API's, it looks as though you are using the [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#hook-api)

```html
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

You can also use the Styled component API. An [example](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#adapting-styled-components-api) is below for Material UI which applies the styles within the component, which is useful if the styles change based on conditions such as what props are passed in. In that case it is good design to encapsulate the logic within that component, rather than importing and external class.

```html
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// Like https://github.com/brunobertolini/styled-by
const styledBy = (property, mapping) => props => mapping[props[property]];

const MyButton = styled(({ color, ...other }) => <Button {...other} />)({
  background: styledBy('color', {
    red: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    blue: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #2196F3 30%, #21CBF3 90%)',
  }),
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: styledBy('color', {
    red: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    blue: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(33, 203, 243, .3)',
  }),
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
});

function AdaptingStyledComponents() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton color="red">Red</MyButton>
      <br />
      <br />
      <MyButton color="blue">Blue</MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AdaptingStyledComponents;
```

In that scenario, it is better to keep the styles within that component. So overall it is a balance between importing shared styles and applying local styles.